# Why is predicate misinterpreting parameters' values when called in recursive function

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to create a extended treeview control inheriting from the existing winform TreeView control. 
Created a `Load()` function in the class TreeViewEx. In this function the dataSource is looped in a foreach. This foreach then calls the `Where()` extension method on the looping dataSource passing to it a methode (which takes as parameter the current element) returning a predicate.
This predicate misintepretes the parameter value passed to it. It seems to be using previous parameter values.

value of arg in method before returning predicate

[image: value of arg in method before returning predicate]

value of arg when debugger enters predicate

[image: value of arg when debugger enters predicate]

Initially i thought this behavior was due to the fact that i am iterating through an `Enumerable` not a list, so i change the different enumerables to List but nothing changed. Also tried to instatiate the returned predicate but nothing.

Load function :

```cs
public Func<T, Func<T, bool>> GetChildrenPredicate { get; set; }
.
.
.
public virtual void Load(List<T> dataSource = null)
{
    try
    {
        if (CreateNode == null)
        {
            OnError?.Invoke(this, new ArgumentNullException("CreateNode"));
            return;
        }
        if (GetParentKey == null)
        {
            OnError?.Invoke(this, new ArgumentNullException("GetParentKey"));
            return;
        }
        if (GetChildrenPredicate == null)
        {
            OnError?.Invoke(this, new ArgumentNullException("GetChildrenPredicate"));
            return;
        }

        var finalDataSource = dataSource ?? DataSource;

        TreeNode node = null;
        BeginUpdate();
        foreach (var item in finalDataSource)
        {
            node = CreateNode(item);
            node.Tag = item;

            if (this.Nodes.Find(node.Name, true).Count() == 0)
            {
                var n = this.Nodes.Find(this.GetParentKey(item), true).FirstOrDefault() as TreeNode;

                if (n == null)
                {
                    this.Nodes.Add(node);
                }
                else
                {
                    n.Nodes.Add(node);
                }

                List<T> children = finalDataSource
                                  .ToList()                                   
                                  .Where(this.GetChildrenPredicate(item))
                                  .ToList(); //this.GetChildrenPredicate is
                                //the property func generating the 
                                //predicate set by a different class

                if (children.Count() > 0)
                {
                    // Recursively call this function for all childRows
                    Load(children);
                }

            }
        }
        EndUpdate();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        OnError?.Invoke(this, ex);
    }
}
```

GetChildrenPredicate :

```cs
private Func<ORM.DataModels.Menu, bool> GetChildrenPredicate(ORM.DataModels.Menu arg)
{

    return (ORM.DataModels.Menu m) =>
    (m.Lepere == arg.Codmen) ||
    (m.Lepere == null && arg.Codmen == "_" + m.Niveau);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the break-point on the line you are inspecting. This means that this code has not yet been executed. I might display the values of a previous call cached by the debugger.

If you want to inspect the result of the return-expression, assign it to a temporary variable first.

```
Func<ORM.DataModels.Menu, bool> predicate =  (ORM.DataModels.Menu m) =>
    (m.Lepere == arg.Codmen) ||
    (m.Lepere == null && arg.Codmen == "_" + m.Niveau);
return predicate; // <== Set breakpoint here
```

---

Maybe it helps to assign the argument to a local variable first, to force the lambda to use the current value.

```
string codmen = arg.Codmen;
return (ORM.DataModels.Menu m) =>
    (m.Lepere == codmen) ||
    (m.Lepere == null && codmen == "_" + m.Niveau);
```

Comment: Break point set there doesnot give me any result. If it is a cached value by debugger why is the test still failing where the result of the **Func** has to be true ?

Comment: What do you mean by *"doesnot give me any result"*? Note that the predicate itself is not executed here, but the expression is executed to **create** the predicate. This predicate captures the value of `arg.Codmen` and uses it when the predicate is called later. What your method returns is not a `bool` but a `Func<TArg, TReturn>`.

Comment: Excuse me but it seem as if you're not getting me. Please check in the **Load()** function. That is where the method **GetChildrenPredicate** is invoke and it's result is directly used by the **Where()** extension method. The predicate returned when called returns a bool. When a break point is inserted inside that predicate the value of **arg.Codmen** used is not the expected captured value of the predicate

Comment: thanks for updating your answer. But unfortunately nothing changed

Comment: What happens if you write `var temp = item;
List<T> children = finalDataSource
    .ToList()
    .Where(this.GetChildrenPredicate(temp))
    .ToList();` using another temp?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the solution. Actually i did not realized that  `finalDataSource` was overriden on each call of `Load()`. I was only focused on the weird behaviour of the predicate. just had to used the global DataSource property defined in the class.

```
List<T> children = this.DataSource.Where(this.GetChildrenPredicate(item)); //<= changed local variable finalDataSource to the defined property this.DataSource
```